# MassTransit + Entity Framework Core - "More than twenty 'IServiceProvider' instances" exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, masstransit

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with Entity Framework Core and MassTransit configured in the following way:

```cs
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database");

var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(connectionString);

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(dataSourceBuilder.Build());
    options.UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
});

services.AddMassTransit(options =>
{
    options.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
    options.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<ApplicationDbContext>(config =>
    {
        config.QueryDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        config.QueryMessageLimit = 100;
        config.UsePostgres().UseBusOutbox();
    });
    //options.UsingRabbitMq(...);
});

// More stuff

var app = builder.Build();

// Run Database migrations
if (applicationOptions.Database.SeedOnStartup)
{
    using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();

    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

    if (context.Database.IsRelational())
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();
        var migrationService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMigrationService>();
        await migrationService.SeedDatabaseAsync();
    }
}

// Invoke whatever middleware I have
app.Run();
```

After N amount of time (without anyone sending any requests), the API itself just throws an exception and it shuts down with the following message:

```
[16:02:22 ERR] ProcessMessageBatch faulted
System.InvalidOperationException: An error was generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ManyServiceProvidersCreatedWarning': More than twenty 'IServiceProvider' instances have been created for internal use by Entity Framework. This is commonly caused by injection of a new singleton service instance into every DbContext instance. For example, calling 'UseLoggerFactory' passing in a new instance each time--see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869049 for more details. This may lead to performance issues, consider reviewing calls on 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' that may require new service providers to be built. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'CoreEventId.ManyServiceProvidersCreatedWarning' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.EventDefinition.Log[TLoggerCategory](IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.CoreLoggerExtensions.ManyServiceProvidersCreatedWarning(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, ICollection`1 serviceProviders)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<GetOrAdd>g__BuildServiceProvider|4_1(IDbContextOptions _, ValueTuple`2 arguments)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c.<GetOrAdd>b__4_0(IDbContextOptions contextOptions, ValueTuple`2 tuples)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, Boolean providerRequired)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserContext`5..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext`8..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
   at MyApp.API.DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions`1 options) in D:\Development\MyApp\MyApp.API\DataAccess\ApplicationDbContext.cs:line 15
   at ResolveService.ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext undefined, ServiceProviderEngineScope undefined)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.BusOutboxDeliveryService`1.DeliverOutbox(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.BusOutboxDeliveryService`1.DeliverOutbox(Int32 resultLimit, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/BusOutboxDeliveryService.cs:line 94
   at MassTransit.Util.RequestRateAlgorithm.RunRequest(RequestCallback requestCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MassTransit.Abstractions/Util/RequestRateAlgorithm.cs:line 157
   at MassTransit.Util.RequestRateAlgorithm.Run(RequestCallback requestCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MassTransit.Abstractions/Util/RequestRateAlgorithm.cs:line 150
   at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.BusOutboxDeliveryService`1.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) in /_/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/BusOutboxDeliveryService.cs:line 76
```

My `ApplicationDbContext` derives from `IdentityDbContext<>` and is shown here. The line 15 which is mentioned in the stack trace is the constructor of the `DbContext`:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, long, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>
{
    // public DbSet<MyTable> Data { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.AddInboxStateEntity();
        builder.AddOutboxStateEntity();
        builder.AddOutboxMessageEntity();
    }
}
```

To try to replicate the issue, I lowered the query delay in MassTransit's `AddEntityFrameworkOutbox()` to 5 seconds (`config.QueryDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);`) and sure enough, after about 100 seconds, it does automatically throw the exception. I genuinely have no idea what the proper workaround for this is nor what I have misconfigured, because basically every resource out there registers MassTransit and Entity Framework Core in the exact same way.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you search for the actual error, you'll see there are dozens of answers related to the `DbContext` and how it's configured, differences that might be causing it to think it's unique each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging for some time (open source software for the win!), it looks like I've been calling `dataSourceBuilder.Build()` every time a DbContext was resolved.
The solution was fairly simple - extract the built NpgsqlDataSource outside of the `AddDbContext<>` call. Ultimately, it seems to be working well now and the DbContext registration looks like this:

```cs
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database");
var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(connectionString);
var dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.Build();
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(dataSource);
    options.UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
});
```